# How to add IP address of authentificated users in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Could you please help me with Django-Admin part in order to save and see the last used IP address for the authenticated user(session).

In my understanding I have to customize the user model but how to do this in the best easiest way ? Also at what time/state/moment should I define IP for for the User model ?

I expect to have additional field in the User model which contains the last used client IP

Comment: Please refer to [MCVE guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by providing an example of the attempt you made to fix your issue. StackOverflow is not a coding service, it is a platform for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd highly recommend installing [django-useraudit](https://github.com/muccg/django-useraudit) in your app. It will store more than the last successful login IP Address. It will save (for **both** successful and failed* login attempts):

- Username
- IP address
- Forwarded by
- User Agent
- Timestamp